# html display in cefsharp with distortion

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

[image]

I have a WPF application, when I use cefsharp display the HTML, it looks blurry。
I have tried to use the following code, but it does not work.

```
 settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
 settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-compositing", "1");
 settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-begin-frame-scheduling", "1");
 settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync", "1");


Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
```

Are there other ways to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In your control XAML try changing `BitmapScalingMode`

```
<cefsharp:ChromiumWebBrowser RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
```

As per this [thread](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/166), some people had it solved. Also might be interesting to experiment with `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on parent control.